# Issue with Updating elements in a 2D Matrix

Tags: python, matrix

```py
n = 5
k = 6

matrix = [[j for i in range(n)] for j in range(k)]

for element in matrix[3]:
    print(element)
    element = 100

print(matrix)
```

I expect to see one row in my matrix to be all 100 at the end, but the values are all still initial values, why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

When you run:

```py
for element in matrix[3]:
    element = 100
```

all you're doing is changing the element inside the for loop. When another round of the for loop starts, element is changed back to what it should be, i.e.: the next element in the matrix. You can think of element as a temporary variable that changes every run of the loop.

More importantly, 'element' is now separate from the matrix. Changing 'element' will not change the matrix. You need to directly call on the matrix element you want to change and assign it whatever value you want to set it to. The proper way to do this would be to do:

```py
for i in range(len(matrix[3])):
    matrix[3][i] = 100
```

Check the code below for what the right code should look like.

```py
n = 5
k = 6

matrix = [[j for i in range(n)] for j in range(k)]

for i in range(len(matrix[3])):
    matrix[3][i] = 100

print(matrix)
```

Comment: What would be the right code? I am confused on how is it possible that the elements could be changed, but not the matrix, since the elements are in the matrix.

Comment: You can find the right code at the bottom of my answer. I have expanded the explanation. Hope it's all clear now.